# Change specific row name in a specific column

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I want to change the name of a *specific* row in a *specific* column. I have troubles navigating around in my **dataframe** to change the name of this specific object.

[image]

For example: I want to change "RowName1" in the column "ColumnName1"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a bit confusing because "row name" is not in a column.  What do you mean by rowname? Is it just a character value?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just want to change the (character)value "RowName1" to something else. I don't know how to navigate through the dataframe to call this specific value and rename it.

Comment: Okay is it unique? So you can just say  `ColumnName1 == RowName1`  to find the value you want to change?

Comment: Yes, it's unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found what I was looking for:

```
df[df == "OldValue"] <- "NewValue"
```

Comment: That's almost right!  df$ColName1[df$ColName1 == "OldValue"] <- "NewValue"  ... you an accept your own answer!